# Nonce failing on form submission

Tags: plugins, errors, security, nonce

I'm updating some code in one of my WordPress plugins by adding a nonce to improve security. The plugin that has a form that generates some output that the user can copy and paste as a shortcode. At the bottom of the settings form I have a second form that resets the first form to its defaults.

As the headline says, the nonce keeps failing.

```
<?php
/**
 * Form reset.
 *
 * @package Foobar/foobar
 */

// $parent and $token construct the page slug. Settings form and these variables omitted for clarity.

$html  = '<form id="my-reset" name="my-reset" method="post" action="options-general.php?page=' . $this->parent->token . '&tab=generator">';
$html .= wp_nonce_field( 'options-general.php?page=' . $this->parent->token . '&tab=generator', 'my_reset_nonce' );
$html .= '
  <p class="submit"><input name="reset" class="button button-secondary" type="submit" value="' . esc_html__( 'Reset the Shortcode Generator', 'textdomain' ) . '" >
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
    </p>
</form>';

if ( isset( $_POST['reset'] ) ) {
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( 'options-general.php?page=' . $this->parent->token . '&tab=generator', 'my_reset_nonce' ) ) {
        die( esc_html__( 'Invalid nonce. Form submission blocked!', 'textdomain' ) );
    } else {
        // Logic to reset the settings form.
    }
};
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nonce_field/

Comment: Yes. That's how I figured out this code. FWIW I've also tried

 `$nonce = $_REQUEST['_wpnonce']; if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'options-general.php?page=' . $this->parent->token . '&tab=generator', 'my_reset_nonce' ) ) { // Error. }`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure what was wrong with my original code, but [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113763/wp-verify-nonce-keeps-failing?rq=1) put me on the right path.

To generate the nonce, use:

```
wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'my_reset_nonce',true,false);
```

To verify, use:

```
if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_reset_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( ( $_POST['my_reset_nonce'] ), plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) {
    die;
} else {
    // Reset the form.
}
```

Various other variables, conditionals, sanitizing, etc. omitted for clarity.

Comment: [See this thread](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/869) for a discussion on sanitizing `wp_verify_nonce`.