# select box not checked and is not saved

Tags: front-end

I needed to assign categories to post from frontend and found this [fantastic thread here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43419/how-do-i-create-a-way-for-users-to-assign-categories-to-a-post-from-the-frontend) on this site, which generates a form at frontend with selectboxes. The plugin automatically appends the form after the content and works like charm.

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: WPSE Crowded Cats
Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43419/how-do-i-create-a-way-for-users-to-assign-categories-to-a-post-from-the-frontend
Description: Allow visitors to change categories of posts. Ready to use with custom taxonomies and post types. 
Version: 0.1
Author: WPSE
Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2110/maugly
License: GPL2
*/

add_action('plugins_loaded','wpse_init_crowd_cats_class');
function wpse_init_crowd_cats_class(){
    new WPSECrowdCatsClass();
}

class WPSECrowdCatsClass { 
    function __construct() {
        // APPEND THE FORM AUTOMATICALLY TO EVERY POST
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this,'append_form' ) );

        // TEMPLATE ACTION TAG TO BE USED IN THEME
        // Usage: do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form');
        // Usage: do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form', $post_id, $taxonomy );
        add_action( 'wpse_crowd_cats_form', array( $this,'wpse_crowd_cats_form' ), 10, 2 );

        // FORM PROCESSING
        add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this,'process_request' ) );
    }

    function process_request(){
        // check submission
        if ( ! isset($_POST['crowd-cat-radio']) || ! is_array($_POST['crowd-cat-radio']) )
            return;

        //TODO: check nonce
        // sanitize and check the input
        $suggested_terms = array_map( 'absint', $_POST['crowd-cat-radio'] );
        $post_id = absint( $_POST['crowd-cats-pid'] );
        $tax = $_POST['crowd-cats-tax'];
        if ( ! taxonomy_exists($tax) )
            return;

        // Allow only existing terms. Not sure if this is needed.
        $args = array( 'hide_empty' => false );
        $args = apply_filters( 'mcc_allowed_terms_args', $args, $post_id, $tax );
        $args['fields'] = 'ids';
        $allowed_terms = get_terms( $tax, $args );
        foreach ( $suggested_terms as $key => $term_id )
            if ( ! in_array( $term_id, $allowed_terms ) )
                unset( $suggested_terms[$key] );

        // Add terms to taxonomy
        $affected_terms = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $suggested_terms, $tax, false );
        update_term_cache($affected_terms);
        return $affected_terms;
    }

    function get_form( $post_id=null, $tax='category' ) {
        if ( is_null($post_id) || ! taxonomy_exists($tax) )
            return false;

        $args = array( 'hide_empty' => false );
        $args = apply_filters( 'mcc_get_terms_args', $args, $post_id, $tax );
        $all_terms = get_terms( $tax, $args );

        if ( ! $all_terms )
            return false;

        $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $tax, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        $permalink = get_permalink( $post_id );
        $out = "<form id='crowd-cats' action='$permalink' method='POST' >
            <ul >";

        foreach ( $all_terms as $t ) :
            $checked = in_array( $t->term_id, $post_terms) ? 'checked' : '';
            $out .= "<li>
                        <input type='checkbox' id='crowd-cat-$t->term_id' name='crowd-cat-radio[]' value='$t->term_id' $checked /> 
                        <label for='crowd-cat-$t->term_id' >".esc_attr($t->name)."</label>
                     </li>";
        endforeach;

        $out .= "</ul>
                <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='crowd-cats-submit'/>
                <input type='hidden' value='".esc_attr($tax)."' name='crowd-cats-tax'/>
                <input type='hidden' value='$post_id' name='crowd-cats-pid'/>";

        //TODO: set nonce
        $out .= "</form>";
        return $out;
    }

    function append_form($content){
        global $post;
        if ( 'post' != $post->post_type )
            return $content;

        $form = $this->get_form( $post->ID );
        if ( ! $form )
            return $content;

        return "$content \n $form";
    }

    function wpse_crowd_cats_form( $post_id=null, $taxonomy='category' ) {
        if ( is_null($post_id) ) {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;
        }
        echo $this->get_form( $post_id, $taxonomy );
    }
} // end of class
```

However I did not want the form to appear right after the content but after a few other important divs i have, after the content. So I used the following action tag ( mentioned in code as commented out lines) to use it in the template single.php. Doing so the form appeared in the desired place.

```
<?php do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form'); ?>
```

The issue is it does not remains selected on submit neither the option gets saved. Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Can you also share the code snippet you have been trying?

Comment: @MarutiMohanty , I am using the same code so I just copied the same code from the thread. It works fine when used as it is but gives the issue mentioned above when used as template tag.

Comment: Did you try with `do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form', get_the_ID());`?

Comment: @brasofilo , yes..exactly what i needed. thanks. How do I accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code documentation:

```
// TEMPLATE ACTION TAG TO BE USED IN THEME
// Usage: do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form');
// Usage: do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form', $post_id, $taxonomy );
```

If the `do_action` is going to be placed in the loop, then `do_action('wpse_crowd_cats_form', get_the_ID());` should work.